# Creating a Template based PHP BLOG

Tags: php, templates

I just created a BLOG Script. I'm using `foreach` to loop and display the posts. But now I want to create a template engine like Wordpress. How can I do that? I'm new to PHP. I don't have any idea to do this.

I tried using `file_get_content`. For example:

```
file_get_contents("template_dir/template_name/index.php");
```

But there is a problem with CSS and images. That's my first problem. Anyone please help me to create this.

Comment: The following article might be interesting for your: [When Flat PHP meets Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html). It covers how to seperate the display from your database queries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To bring in files you use `include()` or `require()`

However, I don't see why so many people insist on trying to reinvent the wheel. If you are building a blog install Wordpress and code your own Wordpress theme. Wordpress has been in development for years and is now not only one of the best blogging engines, but a very powerful cms capable of powering any type of site.

Comment: i know bro, but i want to know how to do this, also tried include() and require() but only problem is the css and images

Comment: @Akhil instead of the omnipresent Wordpress everyone keeps suggesting, I second your will to learn and I reraise with my suggestion: try some php framework, maybe CakePHP or Yii wich both have a blog tutorial that will help you on learning good coding practices (which Wordpress doens't do) and a lot more

Comment: Of course Wordpress doesn't teach good coding practice, but then who is the authority on good coding practice for an open source language, good practice is open to interpretation and dependent on goals. If you wanted to learn of course you should look at the tutorials and learn, it is fantastic. But if it wasn't a learning experiment, and you wanted to start running a blog then Wordpress is the way to go, because it would take you about 5 years to learn everything and then another 5 years to build anything even close

Comment: you are right bro, but i cant find a tutorial that teeches creating a template based blog or forum. all are saying about parsing the code like {title},{name},etc.... i know to parse the code.. i hope you understand.. anyway thnks for your reply.